# spark merge datasets based on the same input of one column and concat the others

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Currently I have several `Dataset[UserRecord]`, and it looks like this

```
case class UserRecord(
  Id: String,
  ts: Timestamp,
  detail: String
)
```

Let's call the several datasets `datasets`.
Previously I tried this

```
datasets.reduce(_ union _)
  .groupBy("Id")
  .agg(collect_list("ts", "detail"))
  .as[(String, Seq[DetailRecord]]
```

but this code gives me an OOM error. I think the root cause is `collect_list`.

Now I'm thinking if I can do the `groupBy` and `agg` for each of the dataset first and then join them together to solve the OOM issue. Any other good advice is welcome too :)

I have an `IndexedSeq` of datasets look like this

```
|name|   lists      |
| x  |[[1,2], [3,4]]|

|name|   lists      |
| y  |[[5,6], [7,8]]|

|name|   lists         |
| x  |[[9,10], [11,12]]|
```

How can I combine them to get a `Dataset` that looks like

```
|name|          lists               |
| x  |[[1,2], [3,4],[9,10], [11,12]]|
| y  |[[5,6], [7,8]]                |
```

I tried `ds.reduce(_ union _)` but it didn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate after union:

```
val ds2 = ds.reduce(_ unionAll _).groupBy("name").agg(flatten(collect_list("lists")).as("lists"))
```

Comment: I made a mistake in the description, the `lists` are actually lists of lists. Should I do one more `collect_list` afterwards? Could you please modify the answer?

Comment: I have taken that into account already. Have you tried my answer?

Comment: Yes I tried that. It seems like the answer above messed up with a `sortBy` following in that the sorted result doesn't look right. Anyway I'll dig deeper thanks!

Comment: can you provide a [mcve] that describes your problem?